# ion-option-buttons showing if i put ng-change on ion-toggle

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Good day! Im fairly new to ionic and mobile dev. Im making a simple reminder app and Im implementing **ion-toggle**
Here what my code looks like,

```
<ion-item class="item-avatar" ng-repeat="med in meds.medications" >
     <img ng-src={{med.medicine.image_url}} style="top: 25px;">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-50 col-center">
          <h2>{{ med.medicine.name }}</h2>
          <p>{{ med.dose +' '+med.type }}</p>
          <p style="font-weight: bold" >{{ med.time }}</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col" style="border: 0">
          <ion-toggle ng-checked="!med.status" toggle-class="toggle-calm" style="border: 0;">&nbsp;</ion-toggle>
        </div>
     </div>         
    <ion-option-button class="button-positive" ng-click="meds.showEditMed(med)">Edit</ion-option-button>
    <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="meds.showDeleteMed(med)">Delete</ion-option-button>
</ion-item>
```

I have a very weird problem, whenever I put **ng-change** on my *ion-toggle*, the option button shows up. Ive looked up the net for some solutions, none of which have this the same problem.
Here is an image of my problem[image]

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **ng-model** on ion-toggle, here is the sample code:

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="someVariable" ng-checked="!med.status" toggle-class="toggle-calm" style="border: 0;">&nbsp;</ion-toggle>
```

Answer (score 0):

ooops, my bad. I forgot to put ng-model on the ion-toggle.